# Verify Furry theorem in scalar QED

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I want to verify Furry theorem in scalar QED. Consider a process with N photons. Is it correct to say that at 1 loop the two classes of Feynman diagram that contribute are the following?
[image]

[image]

with $n+2m = N$.
I know that there are many other diagrams with all the permutation, but I am asking if there are other "class" of diagram which I have neglected.
Actually, if I use the Feynman rules for these two loops, I find that each diagram cancels out with the diagram with inverted arrow. Is that correct?